# How to track Google Analytics Events in Server Side asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, events, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

Is there a way to track Google Analytics Events from Server Side in ASP.NET, the requirement is the the Event should be tracked on button click after some functionalities are executed on Serverside. ? OnClientClick of button, we cannot fulfill this requirement completely as some time serverside functionalities can fail but the event will get tracked in Google? Please help me in this regard.

Appreciate expert answers.

Thanks in Advance,
Raj

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do server side google analytics, see this project for example:

http://code.google.com/p/php-ga/

Basically you just make requests server side to http://www.google-analytics.com/utm.gif with the right parameters.

Comment: Also see the Silverlight Google Analytics binding:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/silverlightTrackingIntro.html

Answer (score 1):

You could also send the event to google via the client on the NEXT request.

1. User clicks the button
2. Server receives request, does some steps
3. Steps pass, server decides the event happend
4. Server renders javascript into the response to track the even
5. Client receives the response, executes the javascript